# Logo not central when media queries are in effect

Tags: html, css, media-queries, center, graphical-logo

I have my logo central of the nav with two navigqtion links either side of it. On screens +768px the logo is bang on in the middle which is great but when i shrink the window it slowly goes off center. 
Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/82awaxdy/

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="section-1"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <nav>
                    <div class="small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#section-1">Home</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                    <div class="small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#section-2">About</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                    <div class=" small-4 medium-4 large-4 columns logo"><img alt=
                    "Karen Thomas Art"  src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
                    </div>


                    <div class="small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#section-3">Work</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                    <div class="small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#section-4">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a {
    color: #7FA7B2;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    color: #929396;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul {
}
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 13px;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 640px) {
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    #container {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .logo img {
        margin: 0, auto;
    }
    nav {
        padding-right: 10%;
    }
    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    nav ul li {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #container {
            margin: 0;
        }
        .logo img {
            margin: 0, auto;
        }
        nav {
        }
        nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        nav ul li {
            font-size: 11px;
        }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
            body {
                margin-left: 10%;
                margin-right: 10%;
            }
            #container {
                margin-top: 5%;
                margin-bottom: 5%;
                background-color: #fefefe;
                box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
            }
        }
```

[image: Nav]

Comment: `Karen Thomas Art` ..thats the logo?

Comment: @NoobEditor yeh, cant use the real one so ive used one from lorempixel.com

Answer (score 0):

You have given `margin: 0, auto;` to `img` but this wont center the image as it as no `width` defined.In order to make it a generic across all browser / device width, simplest would be to add this:

```
.logo {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        border:1px solid green; /* just to show in fiddle*/
    }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/82awaxdy/2/)

Comment: thanks @NoobEditor, although the width:100% is making the logo huge?

Comment: i am not aware of your page design....if it goes with the layout, its fine...but on fiddle, yeah, it looks odd!! :)

Comment: that looks perfectly fine...but if you are considering Media Query on this,i'll suggest you hide this when MENU converts to drop down...that way, it would look better!! :)

Comment: Hi @NoobEditor, Sorry but it still doesnt seem to be working! The logo is now hugging the left margin and is still massive.

Comment: i showed fiddle for only one media query...have you made changes to the other ones too?